# Benchmarking Akka with the Matrix Vector example

Tags: performance, scala, akka

I have tried to benchmark the Akka Framework with a matrix vector multiplication. For this very data intensive problem I measured absolute runtimes for different number of workers on a 16 core machine.

I have used the following configuration:

```
akka {
    logConfigOnStart=off
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 16
        parallelism-factor = 3.0
        parallelism-max = 16
    }
}
```

For different number of workers, I would expect a better runtime the more worker I use, but I observe a very bad speedup. I have measured absolute runtimes and ploted them on a barchart.

Figure: [different number of workers](https://github.com/perdacherMartin/Pap/blob/master/figures/nrWorkers.png)

For more details, I want you to have a look on:

the project description on git: [scroll down to Benchmarking Akka](https://github.com/perdacherMartin/Pap/)

or the [implementation](https://github.com/perdacherMartin/Pap/tree/master/matvec/src/main/scala/at/univie/pap/matrixvec) on github.

This is an elaboration for the University, this is why the Actor Model and Akka is summarized in the beginning.

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How do I improve my program to observe a better performance?

Comment: The answer is almost always that you're splitting the work into chunks which are too small.  How does it scale if you use matrices which are 100x bigger (10x by 10x bigger, if they're 2d)?

Comment: thread-pool-executor has horrible scalability, use fork-join-pool. http://letitcrash.com/post/17607272336/scalability-of-fork-join-pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're configuring to use a thread-pool-executor but only provide configuration for a fork-join-executor. thread-pool-executor has horrible scalability, see: http://letitcrash.com/post/17607272336/scalability-of-fork-join-pool

2) Use executor = "fork-join-executor", and I recommend setting your parallelism-factor to between 0.6 and 1.0 you'll have to tune to see which one works best for your setup, you will also need to tune your matrix chunk size to be larger, experiment with this.